# AR.JS with a custom scene with objects created with 3D Force Graph

Tags: three.js, aframe, ar.js

i have created a 3D Chart with 3D Force Graph (https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph). I want to transform that chart into a augment reality web based app with ar.js. 3d-force-graph is using three.js to create a `<canvas>` element. Can I mix that `<canvas>` with ar.js?

I saw in some examples of ar.js that I have to use A-Frame (aframe.js) to create a scene with some objects but my scene is already created.

1. Is there a way to use ar.js with my `<canvas>` created with 3d-force-graph.js without having to use aframe.js at all?
2. Is there a way to make aframe.js to use my `<canvas>` created with 3d-force-graph.js as the scene?
3. Is there a way to export the 3d objects from the `<canvas>` created with 3d-force-graph.js as objects into a aframe.js scene?

I have created a code snippet with the 3D Force Graph.

Thanks

```js
    // Random tree
    const N = 300;
    const gData = {
      nodes: [...Array(N).keys()].map(i => ({ id: i })),
      links: [...Array(N).keys()]
        .filter(id => id)
        .map(id => ({
          source: id,
          target: Math.round(Math.random() * (id-1))
        }))
    };
    const Graph = ForceGraph3D()
      (document.getElementById('3d-graph'))
        .graphData(gData);
```

```html
<head>
  <style> body { margin: 0; } </style>

  <script src="//unpkg.com/3d-force-graph"></script>
  <!--<script src="../../dist/3d-force-graph.js"></script>-->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="3d-graph"></div>

</body>
```